# How do I create a list element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I've tried different solution without much success.

I'm able to add a `<li>` to my list, but the DOM does not recognize it as a list element and thus I'm not able to manipulate it with jQuery later.

This is the last code I've tried, but I get the error msg:

> TypeError: `$('</li>').class` is not a function

Code:

```
 var data = '<div> some stuff</div>';
 var index = "index-" + brand_name[0].toLowerCase();

 $("</li>")
   .class(index)
   .text(data)
   .insertAfter($(".brand_list .main-"+index))
   .css('display','list-element');
```

I've also tried with `<li></li>` and `<li>` but I get the same error.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Use `.addClass` instead of `.class`...

Comment: @RobW Thanks, that helped. My next trick is to add css style. `.css()` is not doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not have that style in the class you add?

Comment: Why are you closing the element like that? --> `$('<li/>')`

Comment: @Steven `list-element` is not a valid display property. Use `list-item`.

Comment: @MichaelPeterson it looks like he is using the css class to store data inappropriately (he appends an index to it) so thats why he would be using .css? To the OP, if this is the case its better to use the `.data()` function http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks guys, I still have a lot to learn about jQuery :)

Answer (score 5):

you should be using `.addClass()` instead of `.class()`. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Do you know how I can add CSS class? `.css()` is not working.

Comment: the `.addClass()` method adds a css class to your element... please read the documentation link I posted.

Comment: Sorry misread your question. `.css()` is correct, but your `display:list-element` is not. try `list-item` instead of `list-element`

Comment: Thanks, that was it. One last question. I'm populating the `<li>` with a few html elements. Like the code is not, the html elements are shown in clear text. So I guess I hve to create these elements much inthe same way. How do I Add these to the li? By creating the element, then us `li.append()` ?